# Cannot import pygame.camera

Tags: import, pygame, camera

I was trying this code to open a webcam with pygame

```
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image
import sys

pygame.camera.init()

cameras = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

print ("Using camera %s ..." % cameras[0])

webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(cameras[0])

webcam.start()

 # grab first frame
img = webcam.get_image()

WIDTH = img.get_width()
HEIGHT = img.get_height()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WIDTH, HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("pyGame Camera View")

while True :
    for e in pygame.event.get() :
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT :
            sys.exit()

    # draw frame
    screen.blit(img, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    # grab next frame    
    img = webcam.get_image()
```

but I got this import error:

...Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pygame_camera_vidcapture.py", line 32, in init
from VideoCapture import vidcap as vc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'VideoCapture'

Comment: Which system and pygame version do you use? See the documentation of [`pygame.camera`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html): *"EXPERIMENTAL!: This API may change or disappear in later pygame releases."*

Comment: I am on Windows and I am using pygame 2.0.0

Comment: @xWourFo pygame.camera only natively supports Linux with V4L2 cameras. Windows support is coming soon, but it isn't here yet. The error you are getting is because pygame is trying to use an alternative backend, the VideoCapture library, which is older, and doesn't seem to support python 3.

Answer (score -2):

Enter

```
pip install pygame.camera
```

into your terminal or command prompt depending on what you are using.

Comment: Is pygame installed?
If it is, then have you tried this?
`py -m pip install pygame.camera` this might work better if you are using command prompt.

Comment: Yes, it is. I've tried, still the same error

Comment: What I've found helpful is to(if you are using an app like VSCode) is to close the tab you are using, create a new file, and then copy paste the code into the new file.

Comment: `pygame.camera` resolves to `pygame_camera` [which is something different](https://github.com/jcemelanda/pygame-camera).